# How to do a indefinite integral of a vector and plot it

Tags: matlab, function, plot, int, integral

I'm new to Matlab and wanted to integrate a section-wise integrated vector.

The code I use to create a vector looks like this:

```
dt=1/1000;
t=0:dt:6;

g(t<=0)=0;
g(t>=0 & t<=1)=1*t(t>=0 & t<=1);
g(t>=1 & t<=3)=1;
g(t>=3 & t<=4)=-1*(t(t>=3 & t<=4)-4);
g(t>=4)=0;
```

I managed to get it work with a `diff()` operation:

```
function [h] = diff_plot(g,t)

dt = 1/1000;

h = diff(g)*1/dt;
h(end) = h(end-1);

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,g);
grid on;
xlabel('Zeit in T');
title('g(t)');

subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,h);
grid on;
xlabel('Zeit in T');
title('h(t)=dg(t)/dt');

end
```

But now i don't know how to do it with the `int()` - function. I always get the error "Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use cumsum in an oposite way of diff function.

Below is description of cumsum function.

> B = cumsum(A) returns the cumulative sum of A starting at the
>   beginning of the first array dimension in A whose size does not equal
>   1.

By multiplying dt, you can calculate integral of discrete function.

```
int_g=cumsum(g)*dt;

plot(t,int_g)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: @KKS I'm working on  integration as well. I have two vectors. One contains the values that need to be integrated and the other contains time stamps from which I can get `dt`. Does this method work for that as well? Thank you